# How to turn escape characters in a string into more escape characters？

Tags: linux

I want  to change  `ccc\|234`  to `ccc\\\\\|234`   by Shell,  someone can give me a suggestion? I used to try solve this problem, like  `echo  ccc\|234 |sed 's/23/4/g'` to change strings, but can't change \ to \\.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "ccc\|234" |sed 's/\\/\\\\\\/g'` is right